# Fastboot's command boot

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, stock-android, fastboot

What can I do with fastboot's boot command?Can i boot into twrp recovey with my bootloader locked?I have to recover some data from my phone but I have adb disabled...I have a nexus 5 and I have thought to some solution but nothing...I don't know what to do

Comment: Double-posting is disallowed even in forums, mind you: [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/156769/boot-huaweis-recovery-on-nexus-5)

Answer (score 2):

Fastboot boot command allows a Bootable image to be started on the device without flashing it permanently... It can be a custom boot kernel image, a recovery environment (TWRP, CWM, Philz), or other custom image. Having an unlocked bootloader is a requirement to boot an unsigned (meaning not stock) image like TWRP.

Comment: Damn!So I can't recover my data:(:(:(

Comment: @AndyYan I suggest you look into unlocking the bootloader without wiping, it is possible in the N4/5 devices... Google can give you that info.

Comment: @acejavelin Now that you mentioned it I remember it somewhat. However I looked it up and seems that it requires a booted-up, functional device to use the alternative unlocker, and if that's the case OP would've recovered data from it easily.