# Boot huawei's recovery on nexus 5

Tags: adb, nexus-5, stock-android, fastboot

I have to recover some data from my phone.I know that huawei's recovery has a function to do a backup of data of android.So I had an idea:can I boot from fastboot through the command "boot" a huawei's recovery in a nexus 5 to recover my data?Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just boot an image from another device.

What exactly is the function you're looking for? Nothing "stock" should be more powerful than a custom recovery (e.g. [TWRP](https://twrp.me/devices/lgnexus5.html)), and backup is a must-have function in them. If by "recovering data" you mean backing them up in recovery and restoring them at a later time then this is the way to go; otherwise please further clarify what you intend to do.

EDIT: I see you [double-posting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/156760/fastboots-command-boot) yet again, -1 for that. @acejavelin has given you the definitive answer there - no, nothing can be done if your bootloader is locked. Unlocking is the first thing you should do when getting hands on a Nexus.

Comment: I am looking for a method to recover my data with my os blocked...I can't access my os.I have some important data in the phone and I would like to recover them.

Answer (score -1):

If i recall correctly, You just need the HTC backup apk installed on another device, you then select the messages, contacts..etc and restore them with the actual apk file... only works from huawei to huawei ...

Maybe you could try a device copy app... they're supposed to be able to clone device data like contacts etc.. using Bluetooth or WiFi